# splitting string and keep characters (regex pattern)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would like to split a String and despair on the regex pattern.

I need to split a string like this: `Hi I want "to split" this (String)` to a String array like this:

```
String [] array = {"Hi", "I", "want", """, "to", "split", """, "this", "(", "string", ")"};
```

This is what I have tried, but it deletes the delimiter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "Hi \"why should\" (this work)";

    String[] array;
    array = string.split("\\s"
            + "|\\s(?=\")"
            + "|\\w(?=\")"
            + "|\"(?=\\w)"
            + "|\\s(?=\\()"
            + "|\\w(?=\\))"
            + "|\\((?=\\w)");

    for (String str : array) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Hi

why
shoul
"

this
wor
)
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code please.

Comment: yep it should be java

Comment: @d_amiD you may to fix `Hi,I,want,",to,split,",this,(,string,)` this is not fine

Comment: So you want to split it on every space, every special character? You want to store the special characters, but not the spaces?

Comment: @ Emz yes exactly. I thought about something with lookaheads, but that doesn't work for keeping the special characters

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far? Also a couple more examples would help. What if there are consecutive marks? What about single quotes? And why do you need this??

Answer (score 0):

You can match the tokens with the regex `\w+|[\w\s]`, assuming that you want the punctuation characters to end up in different tokens:

```
String input = "Hi I want \"to split\" this (String).";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+|[^\\w\\s]").matcher(input);
List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    out.add(matcher.group());
}
```

The output ArrayList contains:

```
[Hi, I, want, ", to, split, ", this, (, String, ), .]
```

You might want to use `(?U)` flag to make the `\w` and `\s` follows the Unicode definition of word and whitespace character. By default, `\w` and `\s` only recognizes word and whitespace characters in ASCII range.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is the solution in `split()`, which works on Java 8 and above. There will be an extra empty string at the beginning in Java 7.

```
String tokens[] = input.split("\\s+|(?<![\\w\\s])(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w)(?![\\w\\s])|(?<=[^\\w\\s])(?=[^\\w\\s])");
```

The regex is rather complex, since the empty string splits between punctuation character and word character need to avoid the cases already split by `\s+`.

Since the regex in the split solution is quite a mess, **please use the match solution instead**.

Answer (score -1):

What language are you trying to write this in?

You could write regex groups something like: (.+)(\s)

This would match any quantity of characters followed by a space

Comment: it should be in java.

but the first " and ( are followed by a character.